# Interface Builder: I can't change names of my objects in the list since I updated

Tags: xcode, object, interface-builder

I just updated Xcode to the latest version 4.2. Only problem is that when I go into Interface Builder I can't change my objects names in the list of objects on the left. I used to be able to click on them twice or mark one and then press enter to change it. But that doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Thanks ind advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can edit the name of the object using the identity inspector's Label field:

[image: screenshot showing label field in identity inspector]

Comment: In Xcode 8, 'Label' is under 'Document' heading, instead of 'Identity' heading.

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying to figure this out too using 4.6.3 and accidentally hit tab while the view object was selected. This allowed me to edit the name.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I was stuck at this. So I tried changing to another alternative in the Lock menu. Then it suddenly updated the view in Interface Builder to reflect the change in Label.